# applicationWillResignActive impact on application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing an application that records a users position at regular intervals whilst walking. I am using an NSTimers to schedule "startUpdatingLocation" followed by calling "stopUpdatingLocation" shortly afterwards to save as much battery as possible.

I want the user to be able to start the application and lock the phone thereby putting the application in an inactive state. My question is when this happens my application (when running via Xcode) seems to continue as normal, but I am curious if there are any differences in the way the application runs in this state as apposed to when the application is running as active?

From the docs it only mentions "applicationWillResignActive" with regards to the application passing through that state on its way to the background. I am more interested in how an application behaves when a used locks the UI and puts the phone away, I just want to make sure its going to keep doing what it should be doing or do I need to take extra measures?

Comment: have a look at [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), specifically Tracking the User’s Location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you app hits `applicationWillResignActive` it can continue to receive location updates if you use the [UIBackgroundModes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) option in your apps info.plist.

Add the `location` key.

It is important that you do not use a timer in the background as timers will run but hold their "fire" until the app becomes active again. Thus you will only get one read when the user comes back to the app. The GPS location accuracy level is what will drive how much the battery is affected.

In your app description in the App Store, Apples requires:

> Continued use of GPS running in the
>   background can dramatically decrease
>   battery life.

You app will not be allowed to go live until the above text is in the description for the user to read.

Comment: That is what I am seeing, with the iPhone plugged in (usb) I can clock the phone and updates come in at 30sec intervals. If I unplug the phone then the iPhone gets the next update, but then does nothing until the iPhone is unlocked. As you say it sounds like the NSTimer is stopping, its just annoying that the timer does not stop when the device is connected via USB.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't remember about the cable being connected or not. Although some of it may depend on whether the phone is locked vs the user switched to another app. I do know that our console log reflected what I described which means the cable was connected at the time. As a person who has worked on 3 GPS apps, I strongly discourage the timer approach. Even if it did work, iPhone GPS is not snapshot accurate. GPS reads becomes over time of use. Therefore stopping and starting leads to mostly inaccurate reads. Users understand all GPS apps use battery.

Comment: Apple on desiredAccuracy: "You should assign a value to this property that is appropriate for your usage scenario. If you need the current loc only within a few kilometers, you should not specify kCLLocationAccuracyBest for accuracy. Determining a loc with greater accuracy requires more time and MORE POWER. When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event delivered by the loc service may not have the accuracy you requested. The service delivers the initial event as quickly as possible then continues to determine the loc with the accuracy you requested when that data is available.

Comment: The above was "chopped down" for size from here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW18

Comment: Much appreciated, I get what your saying, I have been giving CLLocationManager about 15secs to resolve a position and its been working well. I filter out all the crap and 99% of the time end up with a location thats accurate to somewhere between 10-65m.

Comment: My problem is that if NSTimers stop the only solution would seem to be asking for a location update based on significantLocationChange, but from what I can gather thats not going to work as I want updates every 30secs. I also want to use the app in wilderness areas with limited cell coverage (your not going to be swapping cell masts much on a mountain side) I also don't really want to keep CLLocationManager running all the time as that just seems overly wasteful.

Comment: I understand. You could try to find a `desiredAccuracy` that will trigger `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` events that are more frequent than 30 sec. Then you could track the time difference since your last read and determine if enough time has passed to use/record `didUpdateToLocation`. I don't know what that accuracy would be. I can say that `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` will get you a read about every second.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely be testing this on a device.   The simulator doesn't auto-lock, for instance.

applicationWillResignActive is called when the user presses the home button, when another app fires a notification the user accepts (including when a call comes in), and when the device locks.

Look into the multitasking documentation, and what it has to say about background location updates.

My suggestion is that you conserve the user's battery by:
- starting a timer, which when fired, starts location updates (and stops the timer)
- when you get an adequately-accurate position record, stop location updates and restart the timer
- if location updates fail, restart the timer for a longer period. Maybe they're underground.

The most efficient approach is using significant location update service while your application is in the background or the screen is locked on your app. You might get one update every ten minutes or so.

Remember also, the user can disable your app's location services permissions. Especially these days...

Comment: Hi Stephen, I am testing on the device, I was just confused that the iPhones lets the NSTimers (used to get a new location) run when its connected to the mac via usb, *BUT* shuts them off when the iPhone is disconnected from the mac (as it would be in normal use).